# Why do people create virtualenv in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

You can build a container with `Dockerfile` in a few seconds.
Then why do people need to install a virtual enviroment inside the docker container?

It's like a "virtual machine" in a virtual machine ?

Comment: Further isolation is never bad, specially because it causes no overhead. And I believe it's a good habit to keep.

Comment: I must add: a virtualenv is not a virtual machine. Neither is Docker.
virtualenv just creates a copy of python interpreter and creates a separate place for the libraries, isolating where you keep your dependencies. 
Almost the same concept for Docker, you keep your dependencies in layers, and you isolate portions of memory, CPU, storage, network and so on for your container, you don't run a full OS.

Comment: The only reason I see to ever use virtualenv is if you clash with a system dependency e.g. an OS component is using a different version of a python lib.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am working with virtualenvs in Docker and I think there are several reasons:

1. you may want to isolate your app from system's python packages
2. you may want to run a custom version of python but still keep the system's packages untouched
3. you may need fine grain control on the packages installed for a specific app
4. you may need to run multiple apps with different requirements

I think these are all reasonably good reasons to add a little `pip install virtualenv` at the end of the installation! :)

Comment: Since docker policy tends to be "one app per container" the fourth point might not be a good reason.

Comment: thanks @BenoîtLatinier we are probably saying the same thing: I meant that because you are running the app inside a container, this is a good way to isolate its requirements :)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to `RUN pip install virtualenv` earlier in the dockerfile, create the virtualenv directory, and then `pip install` the rest of the packages there, rather than at the end of the installation?

Comment: @Davos yes, of course, it's not the only thing you'd need to run, my comment didn't mean to be literally what you need to add to the dockerfile. Particularly, with python3, you don't even need to install extra packages to create a virtualenv as it's built in

Comment: So it has been a few years since this answer was put in place, but do you still advocate for virtualenv in a docker container?  I ask because both are supposed to provide a level of isolation, so why do you need two levels of isolation if the container should be used for one app and one purpose?

Comment: @Mike true, things have changed a lot. There are serverless lambda functions now, who needs docker anymore apart from some obscure DevOps guy working at AWS? Jokes apart, the increasing need to lock versions to avoid weird conflicts, binary optimisations, and the advent of `pipenv`, are probably strengthening rather than weakening the reasons for this answer. This said, is perfectly reasonable to orchestrate containers with different setups depending on needs, reality is never black or white!

Comment: and with "system" you mean the docker's system?

Comment: @steffen short answer: yes. extended: `isolate your app from system's python packages` here system is whatever the docker image has installed in its belly and running in a container.

Comment: What about using venv to move dependencies from layer to layer https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ ?

Answer (score 32):

Here is my two cents, or rather comments on @gru 's answer and some of the comments.

- Neither docker nor virtual environments are virtual machines
- every line in your docker file produces overhead. But it's true that at runtime virtual environments have zero impact
- the idea of docker containers is that you have one process which interacts with other (docker-)services in a client-server relationship. Running different apps in one docker or calling one app from another inside a docker is somehow against that idea. More importantly, it adds complexity to you docker, which you want to avoid.
- "isolating" the python packages that the app sees (inside a virtual environment) from the packages installed in the docker is only necessary if you need to assure a certain version for one or more packages.
- the system installed inside the container only serves as an environment for the one app that you are running. Adjust it to the requirements of your app. There is no need to leave it "untouched"

So in **conclusion**: There is no good reason for using a virtual environment inside a container. Install whatever packages you need on the system. If you need control over the exact package versions, install the (docker-wide) with `pip` or alike.

If you think that you need to run different apps with different package versions inside a single container, take a step back and rethink your design. You are heading towards more complexity, more difficult maintenance and more headache. Split the work/services up into several containers.

Comment: I second this. Good explanation.

Comment: This is the better answer with solid reasoning.  One of the main purposes of containers is to isolate its "contents" from the rest of the system.  Isolating again inside the container is redundant and unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @steffen There may not be many good cases for use of a virtual environment inside a dock but I believe there are some.
For example, I'm looking into using a virtual environment to isolate the library versions required by my data processing function from the library versions required to pass data to and from external sources.
This could be done by using two containers that interact with each other but in my mind, that would be more complicated (or at least no less complicated) than using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 4):

In our team, we avoid creating Python virtual environments inside Docker containers.

It adds yet another layer of complexity that is pretty much useless in most cases.

In very rare cases, it might be required to not alter system tools that you need and that are written in Python and require some specific versions of Python libraries that would otherwise be overwritten by your own Python package manager at build time.

People might also do it because they are used to virtual environments and keep using them inside Docker images without asking themselves too much questions: it still works, and it might be the default setup they find in tutorials.

Now, these tutorials might suggest creating a virtual environment inside Docker images to be on the safe side, and to avoid all possible clashes with system's python tools.

For instance, [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) is a package manager, but it also insists on using or creating virtual environments for you. I believe that this is not a proper separation of concerns: it would be better to have one tool for package management, and another tool for virtual environment management, if needed.

But because Poetry is mixing up these things (in an understandable attempt to have one-tool-that-solves-it-all), we had to iterate several times on our Dockerfile before we found a simple workaround:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN pip install -U pip poetry

# creates working directory
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src

# installs dependencies
ADD poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/src/
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt

# copies the rest of the source code
ADD . /app/src/

# …
```

No virtualenv needed, and builds now seem to be faster when dependencies are simply installed with pip.

Comment: I should add that `poetry export` currently has some bugs (as of June 2022), and sometimes produces incorrect output that can not be resolved by `pip`.

A few documented issues: [#2480](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2480), [#4209](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4209)