# How to use bash profile in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build an image using dockerfile.
The commands in the dockerfile looks something like these:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
:
:
RUN pip3 install virtualenvwrapper  
RUN echo '# Python virtual environment wrapper' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

After these commands, I will use virtualenvwrapper commands to make some virtualenvs.

If I had only environment variables to deal with in `~/.bashrc`, I would have used `ARG` or `ENV` to set them up.

> But now I also have other shell script files like `virtualenvwrapper.sh` the will be setting some of their own variables.

Also, `RUN source ~/.bashrc` is not working (source not found).

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to edit shell dotfiles like `.bash_profile` in a Dockerfile.  There are many common paths that don't go via a shell (*e.g.*, `CMD ["python", "myapp.py"]` won't launch any sort of shell and won't read a `.bash_profile`).  If you need to globally set an environment variable in an image, use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive.

For a Python application, you should just install your application into the image's "global" Python using `pip install`.  [You don't specifically need a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561981/activate-python-virtualenv-in-dockerfile); Docker provides a lot of the same isolation capabilities (something you `pip install` in a Dockerfile won't affect your host system's globally installed packages).

A typical Python application Dockerfile (copied from https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) might look like

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py"]
```

On your last question, `source` is a vendor extension that only some shells provide; the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/toc.html) doesn't require it and the default `/bin/sh` in Debian and Ubuntu doesn't provide it.  In any case since environment variables get reset on every `RUN` command, `RUN source ...` (or more portably `RUN . ...`) is a no-op if nothing else happens in that `RUN` line.

Comment: You are saying that the environment variables get reset with every `RUN..` Does that use the `~/.bashrc` file to set their variables. In that case I might not need to use source anyways right?

Comment: Even if `/bin/sh` happens to be bash, running `sh -c ...` (which is what RUN usually does) [doesn't read any dotfiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Comment: so, there is no way except ENV to set environment variables in /bin/sh . But ENV will only set just one variable at a time, or can I attach a script file to it for setting the environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to do this from the command line, and avoid messing with the dockerfile entirely. Simply use the -l or --login option to force the shell opened in the Docker image to be a login variant, which will source /etc/profile and the first of the files ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile that is found.

docker run -it --rm docker_image /bin/bash -l

Comment: Thanks for the '-l' option, it can load bash enviroment variables

Answer (score 0):

1. avoid using ~ => put your bashrc in a specific path
2. put source bashrc and your command on the same RUN line with ;

the RUN lines are totally independent from each others for the environment

Comment: I used `RUN echo 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> bashForIndy. 
RUN source bashForIndy; mkvirtualenv dharmesh`. It says **/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mkvirtualenv: not found**

Comment: Needs to be `.`, not `source`, for compatibility with `/bin/sh`. That is to say: `. ~/.bashrc` (assuming the file is otherwise written for compatibility with baseline-POSIX shells)

Comment: Alternately, one can `RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc; mkvirtualenv dharmesh"]` to explicitly specify bash.