# Docker can't find Python venv executable

Tags: python, docker, python-venv

I am trying to create a Docker image for my flask application, shown below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster as build
RUN python3 -m venv /app/venv
COPY . /app
RUN /app/venv/bin/pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3
COPY --from=build /app /app
# ENV PATH = "/app/venv/bin:${PATH}"
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/venv/bin/python3" , "main.py"]
```

Basically, I have two build stages: the first one creates a virtual environment with `venv`, and the second uses a distroless image and copies the virtual environment (along with the rest of my files) from the previous build stage to the new one.

The Docker images builds without issue, but once I try to run the image with `docker run`, I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/app/venv/bin/python3": stat /app/venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

This error confuses me, since I know the python executable is located at `/app/venv/bin`, and I double checked this by exporting the container using `docker export <container name> > container.tar` and exploring the tar file's contents. From what I can tell, I should not be receiving this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: As requested by @RQDQ, below are bare minimum versions of my `requirements.txt` and `main.py`:

`requirements.txt`:

```
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

`main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='build')

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproduction available so I can try to run it here?

Comment: What would I need to provide for you to reproduce it? Do you mean my `main.py` and `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes - I'm only asking because I don't have a lot of python experience but I'm willing to run the build here to see if I can reproduce your error.

Comment: In my experience, a virtual environment needs to _exactly_ match the Python it was initially built with; you may not be able to copy a virtual environment from one image to another with a different Python installation.  If the `python` binary inside your virtual environment is a dynamically linked binary then the "distroless" image might be missing key parts like shared libraries and the dynamic loader.

Comment: I've seen some examples doing this same process though, [like this one from GoogleContainerTools](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/python3-requirements/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` is not standalone environment that can be copied between OSes (or containers):

```bash
$ python -m venv venv
$ ls -l venv/bin/

total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1990 Jun  2 08:35 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  916 Jun  2 08:35 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2058 Jun  2 08:35 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 9033 Jun  2 08:35 Activate.ps1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  239 Jun  2 08:35 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  239 Jun  2 08:35 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  239 Jun  2 08:35 pip3.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   46 Jun  2 08:35 python -> /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    6 Jun  2 08:35 python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    6 Jun  2 08:35 python3.10 -> python
```

As you can see `python` executables are just links to original python executable. It is something like snapshot for your original python that may be reverted or applied. But snapshot is useless if you don't have original base. So you have to create `venv` at same environment that will be used on.

However in case of containers you don't need `venv` at all. Container is already an isolated environment and you don't need one more isolation level with venv. (At least my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827013/what-profit-of-using-virtualenv-with-pyenv-or-docker) about why we need to use `venv` inside container is still don't have an answer)

In short: remove all `venv` related lines:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" , "main.py"]
```

---

However if you need to some extra libraries/compile tools (like `gcc`) to build python libraries when installing it by `pip` then `venv` may be used to be able move only resulted library binaries without store compile tools inside container.

In this case you have to use **same** (or compatible) python base at `build` image and resulted image (`venv` "snapshot" should be applied to compatible base).

Let's see [this example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/python3-requirements/Dockerfile):

```
FROM debian:11-slim AS build
...

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
...
```

Both images at least `Debian` based.

Or [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562835/13946204):

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as compiler
...

FROM python:3.9-slim as runner
...
```

And again base of `builder` and `runner` is the same

---

Looks like `python:3.9.5-slim-buster` and `gcr.io/distroless/python3` are both [Debian based](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#base-operating-system) and should be compatible, but probably it is not fully compatible.

You change endpoint to `ENTRYPOINT [ "sleep" , "600"]`. That will allow to keep container running for 10 minutes. After that attach to running container: `docker exec -it container_name bash` and check is `python` executable exists: `ls -l /app/venv/bin/`

<sub>or just simply use it without `venv` as I said before</sub>

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561981/activate-python-virtualenv-in-dockerfile) regarding why `venv` might be used in a docker image. In short, it's not for extra environment isolation, but rather to get all the necessary build files to run the application and put them into a fresh image to save space.

Comment: @gorilla_glue Most popular answer inside link is `You don't need to use virtualenv inside a Docker Container.` Yes it has addition that we may save space, but I can't see reason why dependencies inside `venv` folder will be smaller than same dependencies inside default `/usr/lib/python/...`  folder. The only one reasonable case I can see that if you doing many complicated builds at `builder` and want to move only resulted binaries to `runner`. Also `runner` should be super slim manually created image without `pip` (because even smallest `python-alpine` has `pip`)

Comment: I'll accept this answer, primarily because of the mention of the distroless image probably being incompatible somehow between the build stages. Making my images identical in both stages fixed the problem.

That being said, as I mentioned before, the use of `venv` was to save space and move files between build stages. Removing this (as you recommend) increases my image size from 1.2 GB to 1.59 GB, which is a noticeable difference. Sure, there are other ways to move those files with a user install or something else, but this seemed like the easiest.

Comment: I'll also add that using the gcr.io distroless image for Python may not have been a good idea, since the repo lists it as experimental, and does not have many options for other versions of Python (I think the base is 3.8, so if you want another version, you are out of luck).