# Docker: executing script in the host environment

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker so this question might be silly for someone. But I stucked in executing the host script using Docker image virtual environment. What I have done is:

- pull an existing image

> docker pull ubuntu:18.04

- install virtual environment

> apt-get install python2.7 virtualenv

> virtualenv venv --python=python2.7

- executing a script in the host using image as a container:

> docker run --rm ubuntu /venv/bin/python test.py

However it throw the error "test.py: No such file or directory"

test.py:

```
print("Hello World from the host")
```

I guess I have to activate the virtual environment but do not know how to. Can someone hep to point out what am I missing?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your image's Dockerfile?  Do you actually need a virtual environment inside the Docker image?  ([Activate python virtualenv in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561981/activate-python-virtualenv-in-dockerfile), for example, has both examples of setting up a virtual environment inside a container and the argument against having one at all.)

Comment: In fact, I could achieve what I want by using mount: docker run -t -i -v $PWD:/work -w=/work ubuntu python2.7 test.py

Answer (score 0):

A container is an [isolated environment](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/). Your host environment and script won't exist in it.
The correct way to achieve what you want is to create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). The Dockerfile will contain a list of instructions, allowing you to build new Docker image.

Yours might look like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7 virtualenv
RUN virtualenv venv --python=python2.7

COPY test.py test.py
```

Then, you build your image:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

and run it:

```
docker run --rm myimage /venv/bin/python test.py
```