# Docker build - use the same shell for all RUN commands

Tags: docker

Is it possible to use the same shell in all RUN commands when building a docker image? As opposed to each RUN command running on its own shell.

Use case: at some point, I need to `source` some file containing environment variables that are used later on. I cannot do this, because the commands run in different shells:

```sh
RUN source something.sh
RUN ./install.sh
RUN ... more commands
```

Instead I have to do:

```sh
RUN source something.sh && \
    ./install.sh && \
    ... more commands
```

Which I'm trying to avoid since it hurts readability, it's error prone and does not allow inserting comments in between commands.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you avoid needing the `something.sh` script entirely, and embed its environment-variable settings in `ENV` directives?  One simple case of this is [Activate python virtualenv in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561981/activate-python-virtualenv-in-dockerfile).

Comment: Sure, I could recreate `something.sh` in terms of Docker build commands, but that file comes from a third-party so every time I get an update I'd need to analyze it again and apply the changes to the Dockerfile. Not very easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have separate RUN statement run in the same shell.

If you don't like the look of concatenated commands, you could write a shell script and RUN that.

You'll have to get it into the container by using a COPY statement.
Or you can use `wget` or `curl` to fetch it and pipe it into a shell. That requires that wget or curl is present in the container, so you might have to install them first.

If you use `curl` and Debian, it could look like this

```
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y curl && \
    curl -sL https://github.com/link/to/my/install-script.sh | bash
```

If you COPY it in, it'd look like this

```
COPY install-script.sh .
RUN ./install-script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will run every command in the same shell, but it seems to persist changes to env vars, including PATH. It allowed me to stop having to call source many times in my file to pick up newly installed PATH binaries. `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-lc"]` Specifically the `l` flag.