# whenever i'm running a docker file for python I'm getting the error

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]    
CMD [ "main.py" ]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from passbook.models import Pass, Barcode, StoreCard, Location
  File "/app/passbook/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from M2Crypto import SMIME
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'M2Crypto'
```

Comment: even I tried virtual env, here my docker file for the same                                                 
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
RUN virtualenv --system-site-packages venv 
RUN source /venv/bin/activate 
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip3 install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "Python3" , "-m" , "main.py" ]

Comment: Can you replicate the error with a local installation or venv of your requirements.txt without a Dockerfile?

Comment: [2/8] RUN virtualenv --system-site-packages venv:

#6 0.228 /bin/sh: 1: virtualenv: not found

------executor failed running [/bin/sh -c virtualenv --system-site-packages venv]: exit code: 127

Comment: this the error i'm getting when I try to use venv

Comment: For what you're showing, trying to use a virtual environment inside Docker will be unnecessarily complicated.  (`source` is not a standard shell command, and the equivalent `.` doesn't "stick" beyond its current `RUN` command, and the Docker image itself is isolation from other Pythons.)

Comment: Where do you expect the `M2Crypto` import to come from?  Is it a library listed in your `requirements.txt` file (and if so, can you [edit] the question to show that)?  Or part of your application source (and if so, can you [edit] the question to show that)?  How are you running the container?

Answer (score -1):

Installing and running the venv would be the answer here, since the error message tells you, it cant find venv.

Try something like this:

> ```
> - pip install virutalenv
> - virtualenv ~/eb-virt
> - source ~/eb-virt/bin/activate
> ```

Comment: You don't generally need a virtual environment in Docker since a container is isolation from other Pythons (some setups using multi-stage builds use it successfully).  The [`venv` tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) has been built into Python for a long time and you don't need to separately install it.  `source` isn't a standard shell command and won't work on _e.g._ Alpine Linux; the `activate` script doesn't work well in Docker.  [Activate python virtualenv in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561981/activate-python-virtualenv-in-dockerfile) has more details.

Comment: It was meant for local testing, forgot to remove the RUN command, like i've mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: thank you, but I'm creating docker image for python, while docker run i'm getting the error like Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>

    from models import Pass, Barcode, StoreCard, Location

  File "/app/models.py", line 8, in <module>

    from M2Crypto import SMIME