# when creating django project via docker container it says sh: django-admin: not found

Tags: python, django, docker, alpine-linux

I created a docker python image on top of alpine
the problem is that when I want to start a django app it can not find django
and it is right bcz when I type pip list, it does not have django and other packages.

ps: when creating the images it shows that it is collecting django and other packages

this is the requirements.txt file

```
Django>=3.2.4,<3.3
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<3.13
```

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="siavash"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
        then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user


ENV PATH = "/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

and this is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

and this is the command that I use:

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django-admin startproject app . "
```

BTW the image is created successfully

Comment: please provide your requirements file

Comment: @ManojTolagekar i provided that

Comment: please tell error what kind of getting

Comment: @ManojTolagekar  sh: django-admin: not found

Comment: just remove versions and build docker file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why this happening i believe is because of a very simple error that's hard to see 
`ENV PATH = "/py/bin:$PATH"`
should be
`ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"`

and you might run into some django-user issue
`USER django-user` so you can use this one i pasted.

Everything else looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. In normal cases, you should not use virtualenv inside Docker Container.
   see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562835/19886776
2. Inside the container there is no need to create an additional "django-user" user because the container is an isolated environment.

Below is code that creates a new Django project through a Docker Container

requirements.txt

```
Django>=3.2.4,<3.3
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

The commands to create the new project

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django-admin startproject app ."
docker-compose up -d
```

To edit files that created by the docker container,
we need to fix the ownership of the new files.

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER app
```

Comment: but what if i want to use venv? what should i do to fix the problem?

Comment: Your error "django-admin: not found" is because you are not inside the venv.  
Django is not installed in your container's general interpreter.  Therefore, you will have to go into the venv, then produce the project.

Comment: how should i activate it sir?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install` instead of `pip install`

If that doesn't work, try installing it separately in a step and check.

Comment: i tried pip3 install but got the same result what shoud i do now sir?