# pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"

Tags: python, linux

Command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Output:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

I wish someone would explain to me what to do and how to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure you were not meant to do this in a virtualenv instead?

Comment: The best way to solve this issue is to create a virtual environment with python3 -m venv path/to/venv. Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip to install the packages in the requirements.txt file. Make sure you have python3-full installed. Once the virtual environment is created and the packages are installed, you can then activate the virtual environment by running source path/to/venv/bin/activate.

Comment: There is a conflict between you district package manager and pip, see into [PEP668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/)

Comment: Im confused.. python3-full is different from python3 ? what is this "full"?

Comment: `pipx` works nicely as well

Comment: @statsconchris [python3-full](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-full) is a dependency package that bundles additional commonly included packages with python.

Answer (score 132):

This is due to your distribution adopting [PEP 668 – Marking Python base environments as “externally managed”](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/).

TL;DR: Use a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Long story: Your distribution is trying to protect you against mixing `apt` provided packages and `pip` provided packages. Mixing two package managers (`apt` and `pip` here) is always a bad idea and the source of many issues.

PEP 668 is a way for distributions to explicitly tell users to avoid falling into this pitfall. Your distribution told you three solutions in the message, but only the 2nd one applies cleanly to your use case:

- Using `apt install python3-xxx`. It does not cleanly apply for you as you're having a `requirements.txt`, not a single dependency. It would work if you have only a few requirements in the file and can do it manually for each, like `apt install python3-xxx python3-yyy python3-zzz`. In this case there's no weird mixing of package managers: you installed `python3` using `apt`, you're installing your dependencies using `apt`: no surprises.
- Using a venv: `python3 -m venv .venv` then `source .venv/bin/activate`, then `pip install -r requirements.txt`. In this case the installation is contained inside the `.venv` directory: no mixing of what apt does and what pip does, no surprises.
- Using `pipx` which does not cleanly apply to your case, `pipx` is good to install and use a program, like `pipx install black`, but here you need to install libraries listed in a requirement file, not a program.

There's another way, that I often use myself because I often need multiple *different* Python versions:

- Use a Python not provided by your distribution, so it does not mess with `apt` installed things and does not adopt `PEP 668`. I often compile many Python interpreters myself using [a short bash function](https://git.afpy.org/mdk/compile-python) which use a `--prefix=~/.local/`, for testing purposes. With those Pythons I use either a venv either a good old `pip install`, in this case `pip` will install it in `~/.local/`, again no clash between `apt` and `pip`, no bad surprises.

Comment: I just ran into this after upgrading to Debian 12. I understand why it's a good practice but I won't say it isn't annoying.

Comment: I need to run `sudo apt install python3-venv` frist.

Comment: Or `sudo apt install python3-full`. But yes, you need it, and it's 100% OK to `sudo apt install` it, that's the right way.

Comment: `source` is a bash extension.  `.` will work in all shells.

Comment: *"I understand why it's a good practice but I won't say it isn't annoying."* - Yea ... it is annoying to be told to do it the right way :-)

Comment: Ended up having to do `--break-system-packages` in addition to the `venv` stuff; possibly because I'm running `pip install` inside a Dockerfile....

Comment: @SarahMesser Looks like your pip install installs outside the venv you created. You may try using `/.../.../venv/bin/python -m pip` to explicitly use Python from the venv (this way you don't need to activate it).

Comment: Things like this make the WORST language to work with, period. Feels like a bad dream but no, this is really what python dev is like.

Answer (score 40):

Use `--break-system-packages` at the end of `pip`.

This will install packages in your local user directory, `~/.local/lib/python3.11`.

```
pip install xyz --break-system-packages
```

Comment: For projects it will be recommented to use venv

Comment: This may get rid of the symptom, but what is the risk? "`--break-system-packages`" sounds scary.

Comment: From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana/75696359#75696359): *"Your distribution is trying to protect you against mixing apt provided packages and pip provided packages. Mixing two package managers (apt and pip here) is always a bad idea"*

Comment: Though it *did* make [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/newbs_getting_started?id=installation-2) install on [Ubuntu 23.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_23.04_(Lunar_Lobster)) (Lunar Lobster): `python3 -m pip install --break-system-packages --user qmk`. But the consequences or risks are unknown.

Comment: This is perfect when creating a linux docker container running a python application. It makes no sense creating a venv inside a container.

Answer (score 16):

Add this to your *~/.config/pip/pip.conf* file:

```
[global]
break-system-packages = true
```

If you want to know more, you can [click here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11776#issuecomment-1434892689).

Comment: This should be the correct answer here. The question is about solving the externally managed Python error. Forcing everyone to use a new approach to Python isn't a solution, it's a philosophical position. I really didn't expect it to be this simple. I was expecting your answer not to work but you really saved my life here. This must be the single most idiotic change the Python devs have made to the project in recent years. I'm now going to have to memorize this as it completely breaks all the packages on VS Code.

Comment: This may get rid of the symptom, but what is the risk? "`--break-system-packages`" sounds scary. Can you provide an explanation, please?

Comment: From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana/75696359#75696359): *"Your distribution is trying to protect you against mixing apt provided packages and pip provided packages. Mixing two package managers (apt and pip here) is always a bad idea"*

Answer (score 7):

For the people coming here to fix this problem because of installed Python version with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (in my case with `python3.12`), assuming your Homebrew installation is in `/opt/homebrew`:

```
# Remove all externally managed files for all Python binaries in Homebrew

rm /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python\@3*/**/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer is correct for regular Python usage, I miss the part about [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29). As nicely explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562835/1657819), many people didn't use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in Docker, because there isn't any real value in it, because containers by definition provide an isolated environment.

As even mentioned in the [PEP-668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) itself, it might be okay to remove the file marker:

> So, builders of base container images may want to ensure that the marker file is not present, even if the underlying OS ships one by default.

However, I feel like using *venv* would be still a better approach, and if one needs a change in the Dockerfile anyway, why not do it the proper way?

```
# Assuming somewhere on top there is already `python3-venv` installed 
# via system package manager, e.g. `apt-get install -y python3-venv`

RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Below you can continue using `pip install` as normal
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.*/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77422355/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with this error inside `pyenv` after upgrading to [Ubuntu 23.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_23.04_(Lunar_Lobster)) (Lunar Lobster). As part of this upgrade, the system Python was also upgraded from 3.10 to 3.11. Re-installing `pyenv` didn't help. I had to:

1. remove all instances of pip discovered via `which pip` (and also `sudo which pip` as it kept pointing me to `.pyenv/shims` and root user didn't have pyenv installed)
2. switch to any pyenv installed python with `pyenv global <version>`
3. install pip back with [`get-pip.py`](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip):

   ```
   wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
   python get-pip.py
   rm get-pip.py
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following. It worked on my [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) and [EndeavourOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EndeavourOS):

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On what system was this tested on?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen even if you're inside a virtual environment if you changed the name of the folder that was generated by `python3 -m venv name`. Restore the old name for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issues related to Python environments being externally managed, because of homebrew installed python version, execute below commmand.

```
rm /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python\@3*/**/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```