# How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?

Tags: python, error-handling, pip

Error message:

> ```
> error: externally-managed-environment
>
> × This environment is externally managed
> ╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
>     python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
>     install.
>
>     If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
>     create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
>     Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
>     sure you have python3-full installed.
>
>     If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
>     it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
>     virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
>
>     See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
>
> note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
> hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
> ```

I use `apt upgrade` and `apt update`.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using and which version?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: This environment is externally managed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75602063/247696) (same question as previous comment, but with the new better title)

Comment: @Shayne This is a Python feature, PEP-668: https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/

Comment: Related: [don't use `sudo` when installing into a venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78003100/running-pip-install-in-virtual-environment-tries-to-install-packages-in-default)

Answer (score 226):

You can use Python's `venv` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696359/10626495).

However if you really want to install packages that way, then there are a couple of solutions:

- use `pip`'s argument `--break-system-packages`,
- add following lines to `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`:

```ini
[global]
break-system-packages = true
```

Comment: .....this error also occurs when you use `--user`......

Comment: 1. As it suggests, some packages can be installed via `apt install xyz`, but that didn't work for some packages for me

2. How can I use Jupyter Notebooks with venv?

Comment: @sagitta You can create a `venv` and then select it as a notebook kernel. If you are using VSCode you can press F1 and then `Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel`. If you run jupyter from console, just activate the venv, install jupyter and start it.

Comment: Problem is in debian 12, it has not python2-virtualenv. And pip return error on install virtualenv for python2. So how can be python2 virtualenv installed without using break-system-packages ?

Comment: @Some I believe it will only break system packages if there is a system package to break. Since you say your OS doesn't have the package, you should be fine to use `--break-system-packages` just once, to install `python2-virtualenv`. (If debian ever does add it as a package, you may want to `pip uninstall` it.)

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs which you never need. Use your system package manager or `pipx` for tools, use `venv`s for non-tools.

Comment: @flyingsheep use-case: installing Tensorflow user-local, but because I have more than one project that uses it I can't afford the multi-GB disk space cost multiple times, so a `venv` is impractical.

Comment: On a chromebook, I used the solution to add to ~/.config/pip/pip.conf and worked very well. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I converted where I was using `pip` to `pip3` and then I added the argument `--break-system-packages` and everything worked! Thank you for this!

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the value by running `python3 -m pip config set global.break-system-packages true`

Answer (score 199):

I've got this error since Python 3.11+ and I've passed this error using this:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Comment: Even better: `sudo mv /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED.old`

Comment: Whats the difference in your answer and the one above?

Comment: @Anm Don't know. Probably haven't seen it when I was on this page

Comment: pipx doesn't currently implement `install -r requriments.txt` making it less useful also. this is by far the simplest solution, and prob the most appropriate. it seems that it is only  set as Externally-Managed until this flag is removed, which is the desired intent. It's a warning such as "let me handle this, i know what I am doing"  and it has to be set by the admin

Comment: Just beware that this may still break your system

Comment: `rm` vs `mv` ..just in case you would like to revert back.

Comment: @BrettHolman Could you share a link or an explanation with more details about the dangers of this?

Comment: This solution works for me, i used the mv option btw

Comment: Python2 was installed with packages for years without issues, this "feature" is a diservice for anyone running in a docker container or on actual hardware. Your lucky if you find someone managing to break the system using python. Maybe possible if you use MACOSX and overwrite pre installed python but that is commonly not done by brew and brew pip.

Comment: This should be the default

Answer (score 61):

The `--break-system-packages` flag in `pip` allows to override the `externally-managed-environment` error and install Python packages system-wide.

```bash
pip install package_name --break-system-packages
```

Note: Usage of this flag shouldn't be abused.

Comment: True, but usage of this flag shouldn't be abused. Large projects like Jupyterlab ship with many dependencies (which keep increasing with each installed extension), so by choosing this route instead of installing through `pipx` (or from the official repos if it's available), one is bound to have a conflict with a system-maintained package.

Comment: It's a nice temporary solution to proceed with what was 'working before' and plan later to fix this

Comment: Could this approach have any potentially negative consequences if used only to install a single package while building a docker image?

Answer (score 40):

I installed [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) first:

```
apt install pipx
```

Then I used `pipx` to install `radian`:

```
pipx install radian
```

Later to confirm the installation location (in my case to configure [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)), I ran:

```
pipx list
```

Comment: Why / how does this work? What does `pipx` do?

Comment: This answer does not really answer the question, also, pipx is not a replacement for pip, because pipx only can install applications, it cannot install system-wide Python libraries. That said, using pipx when possible is still a good advice and may help to keep the system clean. In my case, I ended up doing sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.*/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED to allow myself to use pip normally, but this should be considered a last resort, when alternative solutions either did not work or turned out to be not practical.

Comment: I try to fix it in this way .The package able to be install by pipx.But when I run python xxx.py.It still occur package can't be found .How can it fix it. Tks

Answer (score 35):

Just

```bash
python3 -m venv ~/.local --system-site-packages
```

Be sure `~/.local/bin` is in your path

Then use

```bash
~/.local/bin/pip install ... # --user is implied ;)
```

You could probably just create your own `~/py` directory and initialize everything from there as well. However, I think *.local* is already picked up by `PATH` and import directories.

Comment: This is what I did, although using a newly-created directory in my home dir rather than .local, to avoid mixing a venv with whatever other binaries might end up in .local. Also might have to re-do the venv as python versions roll out, might as well have it isolated. Then I just added the new venv's binary to the start of PATH in .bashrc , re-did pip installs for dependencies I need, and old commands work like they used to.

Comment: That's a very good one for my way of working, but it's even better if you add the "--system-site-packages" option so you still have access to system libraries.

Comment: Got a [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/installing-circuitpython-on-raspberry-pi) explained the `venv` thing. It uses a local folder instead of system folder to install python dependencies, to avoid harming. That's much same to Nodejs and Java devel.

Answer (score 15):

Python is like hell for system administrators... Different software use different versions of many different things.

A few times, I've used pip3 to install things... that break other things.
Sometimes I mix it with "apt-get install".

This error message is just like heaven... because it forces us to do the things right. It means the package manager ([Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)) is responsible for handling dependencies, not *pip*.

It's why we have [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)), or [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

You can create an environment using something like

```
conda create --name thenameofmyapp python=3.8
```

Activate your environment using

```
conda activate pixray
```

Then you can "pip install -r requirements.txt" and it will not break your system :) It will just install things in a specific environment.

Comment: virtualenv is pretty much a complete solution too (And seriously any python dev that doesnt know virtualenv or one of its variants [personally Im a fan of Pipenv] isnt keeping up at all. Reproducability! If it runs in a virtualenv, you can run it in a docker container, and if you can run it in a docker container, your sysadmins will like it very much indeed.

Comment: It shows this error in a conda environment as well, did you try this yourself before writing?

Answer (score 14):

`# rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED`

Comment: [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) was created for a valid reason. It's unwise to ignore it.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76614012/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @micmalti: it was created for *a* reason. Authors of Pip could at least have remembered that one can use their tool to install somewhere else than the system libs, and do something more constructive in that case than refuse to work at all. Frankly, it baffles the mind that after 30+ years that this language exists, the basics like this are still not nailed down.

Answer (score 13):

Set this environment in your OS:

```
PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES 1
```

Or write it in your [Dockerfile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Tools):

```
ENV PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES 1
```

Reference: *[Python 3.11, pip and (breaking) system packages](https://veronneau.org/python-311-pip-and-breaking-system-packages.html)*

Comment: Environment? Do you mean environment variable?

Answer (score 12):

Use:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/pip.conf`
3. Add following line:

   ```
   [global]
   break-system-packages = true
   ```
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> → press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (perform save in the [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) editor)

Everything is updated now you can run `pip install <package_name>`.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/pip.conf` ...

Comment: "Terminal" is ambiguous. Do you mean a terminal or [the Mac application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal)?

Answer (score 9):

That issue is from pip. Just run the command and it will downgrade it.

```
pip install pip==22.3.1 --break-system-packages
```

Surely that will help.

Comment: This solution apparently worked for me. Not idea when it's gonna break again. Programmers always make our lives a mess.

Comment: This may get rid of the symptom, but what is the risk? "`--break-system-packages`" sounds scary. Can you provide an explanation, please? From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana/75696359#75696359): *"Your distribution is trying to protect you against mixing apt provided packages and pip provided packages. Mixing two package managers (apt and pip here) is always a bad idea"*

Answer (score 3):

To fix that error, you can use a Python virtual environment. Here is how you can do that.

#### Install a Python virtual environment

Then you can move into a directory that you wish and create a virtual environment using `virtual env your_folder_name`.
While in the environment you have created, type `source bin/activate`.

Here is an easy way [(video)](https://youtu.be/oTTb6iUuBWQ).

Then that is it.

Comment: There's also `source bin/activate.fish` if you use fish shell

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

`cd /usr/lib/python3.11`

`sudo rm EXTERNALLY-MANAGED`

If you choose to restore this mechanism, create the same file again with the touch command:

```
sudo touch EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

Comment: [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) was created for a valid reason. It's unwise to ignore it.

Comment: @void: are you an alt of @micmalti? PEP 668 was created for *a* reason, by people who should know better (e.g. that sometimes Pip installs things outside of the system directories). Frankly, even PHP got that right more than a decade ago.

Comment: @DomQ I just copied his comment since this answer is copied as well. People will just delete this file without evaluating or even understanding the reason for this mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this problem while running some tasks on a pipeline job that uses the Docker image. I hadn't had this problem before, but since I am not using any specific tag for the Docker image, I am also not very surprised.

I was running the command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

which I replaced with:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --break-system-packages
```

And things worked as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to circumvent the functionality by simply installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/).

Comment: This will not help to install [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_general?id=what-is-qmk) (as an example).

Answer (score 1):

One other way to install packages that are not available via the distribution's package manager may be pip's prefix option, as documented at [packaging.python.org](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/externally-managed-environments/)

> `pip install --prefix=/some/path`
>
> Calls sysconfig.get_preferred_scheme('prefix').

The prefix is distribution dependent. E.g., [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) uses */usr/local* for packages not installed via the system package manager.

Some gotchas are also possible. On [Devuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devuan) (so possibly also on Debian itself and other derivatives), the prefix needed to target */usr/local* is */usr*:

```
pip install --prefix=/usr some_package
```

installs *some_package* in */usr/local* where it is visible to applications installed by the system package manager.

However,

```
pip install --prefix=/usr/local some_package
```

installs *some_package* in */usr/local/local*, which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the author's environment and which package they're trying to install, but perhaps this will help someone else.

I just got this error while using the Python extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). It requires the installation of [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint) in [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), and when attempting to do it, I got the same error. This can be resolved by installing Pylint using [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)):

```
sudo apt install python3-pylint-common
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and you still get this error, try

```
pip cache purge
```

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me after I changed the name of the folder containing my virtual environment. 
If you want to rename a virtual environment, changing the name of the folder doesn't work. I recreated it.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --break-system-packages --upgrade package
```

It does good work on [Debian 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_12_(Bookworm)) (Bookworm).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

To install the package XXX, instead of

```
pip install XXX
```

Try:

```
sudo apt install python3-XXX
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).