# Python pip error "externally managed environment" after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu Server and upgraded it from 22.10 to 23.04. After the installation finished, I tried running one of my python scripts and one of my modules went missing. I tried to reinstall it with `pip3 install playsound` but I get this error:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

As the error says, I tried to install playsound with `sudo apt install python3-playsound` but it's not available through apt.

I also tried `python3 -m pip install playsound` and that gives the same error. I don't really know what else to do because I have never needed to mess with pip like this before.

Any thoughts/ideas appreciated!

Comment: Create a virtual environment like the error describes. I'd advise against installing almost anything system wide, especially if this is a developer machine. Virtual environments help keep projects isolated, makes your dev environment more easily recreatable, and prevents dependency conflicts between different projects you are working on.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did and I still got that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to activate the virtual environment I made.

Comment: could you plz provide full working example?

Answer (score 4):

Just run this command, you`re issue will get fixed.

sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED

Answer (score 1):

Use pipx:

install pipx with `sudo apt install pipx`

then install the package: `pipx install playsound`

Answer (score 0):

fixed with the nexxt comand:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
```

worked for me, you might try, (worked under ubuntu 22 on VMWareWorkstation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it via Linux Advanced Packaging Tool (APT).
Try this one:

```
sudo apt install python3-*pandas*
```

That will install pandas (change it to any other python package that you want to install).