# Install customtkinter

Tags: python, linux, customtkinter

i have a problem while installing customtkinter on my linux pc( i am using kali linux)

i tried pip3 install customtkinter
and it does'nt work here is the ouput:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
```

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

is there any other method ,thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a Python package system-wide, which should be installed via a package manager such as `apt`, `dnf`, etc. The message provides clear solutions for your situation:

- Best practice is to try to use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create Python virtual environment and install necessary packages in the environment.
- Use `pipx` to install packages. I haven't tried this one before, but it seems working.
- Add `--break-system-packages` to the command installing packages. If you fully understand what you are doing, then this can be used as a last resort.

You can see also see the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-everytime-i-use-pip3) as a reference.