# Importing gspread into LibreOffice

Tags: python, gspread, libreoffice-calc

My system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
LibreOffice 7.5.5.2 50(Build:2)

geany 1.38 (built on 2021-10-14 with GTK 3.24.30, GLib 2.68.4)
Python 3.11.4
```

I am trying to import gspread to use with LibreOffice Macros.

```
~$ pip install gspread --user --upgrade
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Where do I go from here? Can I just load the tarball into
`/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/Python` without breaking anything?

I was expecting that gspread would have already been installed in LibreOffice... but when I ran my macro it showed an error saying it could not find it. I then tried to load it on my system and got the External Environment message. Then I realised that maybe I have two Python interpreters installed.... the Geany one and the LO one and as the LO python folder is padlocked... I was hesitant to download the tarball and just stick it in there in case I broke something. So, am a bit flummoxed as to where to go from here.

Comment: What makes you think that `--user --upgrade` would be needed?

Answer (score 0):

The `libreoffice/share/Scripts/Python` directory is for macros, not for installing libraries.

A comment at [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" everytime I use pip3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-everytime-i-use-pip3) says this error occurs with `--user`. LibreOffice uses the system-wide python3 distribution on Ubuntu, so try simply `pip3 install gspread`.

Comment: ~$ pip3 install gspread
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be etc.