# How to install python2 virtualenv in debian 12

Tags: python-2.7, debian-bookworm

I found a problem to install pyton2 virtualenv in debian 12.

To install python2 on debian 12 next command can be used:

```
sudo apt-get install python2
```

But virtualenv exists only `python3-virtualenv`

If try use: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python py2venv`
Will raised error:

```
Exception: Wheel for wheel for Python 2.7 is unavailable. apt install python2-wheel-whl
```

If install virtualenv by pip it return:

```
error: externally-managed-environment
```

So it is not obvious how to install python 2 virtualenv on debian 12.

Comment: Why didn't you do what the error message suggested?

Comment: As I remember, pip install python2-wheel-whl doesn't work. Check now: ERROR: No matching distribution found for python2-wheel-whl

Comment: You should consider installing conda or miniconda that way you can install a python2 package. Here is a forum from [debian](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=154149)

Comment: This page contains only advice, to use anaconda, without installation instruction. Debian contains python2 as is, so I prefer to use default python version. Conda installation will require addition manipulation, and  compatibility checks, whick i did not do.

Comment: "Unfortunately Python2 support is completely dropped in Debian Bookworm." It's not even clear how you installed python2 because it is not in [bookworm](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python2&searchon=names&suite=bookworm&section=all) "Conda installation will require addition manipulation," no it doesn't, you create an environment and have it use python2 done. It has the installation instructions at the end, which are so short you might have missed them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

1. remove python3-virtualenv

   sudo apt-get purge python3-virtualenv
2. sudo apt-get install python2
3. Install virtualenv version <= 20.21.1.

   sudo pip install virtualenv==20.21.1 --break-system-packages

   Instead --break-system-packages, can be used:

   - removing file /usr/lib/python3.x/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED)
   - adding following lines to ~/.config/pip/pip.conf:

     [global]
     break-system-packages = true
     see: [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-everytime-i-use-pip3)

After virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 py2venv

should work.

Addition:
As @matt noted debian 12 droped python2 support at all, so python distribution should be installed from debian 11 distro or conda is used.

Comment: This is bad advice. You shouldn't need to change your python3 version at all. You probably could have used the `pip` found in your python2 bin folder. It seems that python2 is not even in bookworm repository so you had to do something for the `sudo apt-get install python2` to work even.

Comment: I assume, that you don't understand about you write. debian 12 python2 not replace python3 python version, it installed as another not main python version, that can be used together.  python2 and python (python3) commands works without conflicts.

Comment: You've written `sudo apt-get install python2` that does not work with debian 12. Are you using a different release? Have you enabled additional repositories?

Comment: Sorry, debian 12 really dropped python2, and it is very bad in my opinion. Assume that my version have been migrated from debian 11, so there have not been problem to install it.