# I cannot install Tensorflow. How can I resolve this error?

Tags: python

This error appears.

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    For more information visit http://rptl.io/venv

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

The version of Python3 is 3.7.4.
Cryptography is already installed.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3)

Comment: For anyone landing here.
Immediate fix is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641565/4844312