# Uninstall pip packages from old Debian installation

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, debian-bookworm

I run a Debian system where I had installed several python packages via pip on system level. Now I upgraded to Debian 12. It is now suggested to run each application in a venv environment and install the needed packages locally. This I have done, and it works fine.

However when I call pip list on global level, I still see a lot of installed packages. When I try to uninstall those packages, I get this response:

```
pip uninstall pyinotify
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
```

How do I clean up my system?

Tried to uninstall global pip packages. Expected this would work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3)

Comment: Try the [`--break-system-packages` option flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/#cmdoption-break-system-packages) maybe? But be sure to read about all the implications and side effects (I am not necessarily saying this for OP who seems to know what they are doing but also for whoever reads this).