# i want to install pyautogui in ubuntu 23.10 terminal

Tags: ubuntu

i am trying to install python module pyautogui in ubuntu 23.10  but the output is that........

```
pc@virtualbox-ubuntu:~$ sudo python3.11 -m pip install pyautogui
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
pc@virtualbox-ubuntu:~$
```

please tell me the solution of this to install that module

Comment: This happens because you are installing packages in the operating system's copy of Python, which might be upgraded at any time.  For workarounds, see  [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3)