Installing pycairo seems to fail in any attempt
I am trying to install pycairo. I don't know much about environments, I just want to write a fun program :)
This is the error I get:
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.
If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
use a virtual environment:

python3 -m venv path/to/venv
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install xyz

If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with

brew install pipx

You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
will permanently disable this error.

If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.

Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
Soo... I tried a lot of different approches by using tutorial and Stackoverflow, but I am still stuck.
Usually reading the questions from other people here helps, but this time it doesn't.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3

Just a reminder that igraph also has a matplotlib visuaization backend, which at this point has more features than the cairo one.

my input was: pip3 install pycairo
I was like:
pip3 install pycairo

And then:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pycairo
Using cached pycairo-1.26.0.tar.gz (346 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/init.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/init.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/cairo
copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/cairo
running build_ext
'pkg-config' not found.
Command ['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

It basically means that your packages managed by other things (probably apt) and you get this error to avoid breaking things by creating conflicts between pip and apt.
You can solve this problem by executing the following instructions :
python3 -m venv path/to/venv
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install xyz
Here path/to/venv is where you want your env to be located and xyz is the library you want to install.
If you don't care you can simply add --break-system-packages in your pip install command

I don't know why, but opening my terminal again, now I have different error. I ve had this one before but nothing helps :(  I will update my question

@user24895914 can you show the new output ?

I just postet it :) thank you!
