Pip cannot find recent versions of package when trying to install in Docker container
I am trying to run a Docker container in a Jupyter Notebook within AWS Sagemaker. The DockerFile is from a template that worked until I added one additional RUN command with some ML packages I wanted to install.
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3-pip \
         python3-setuptools \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install mlforecast==0.13.1 neuralforecast==1.7.3 optuna==3.6.1 pandas==2.2.2 plotly==5.22.0 statsforecast==1.7.6 torch==2.3.1 utilsforecast==0.1.12

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install scipy==1.2.1 scikit-learn==0.20.2 pandas flask gunicorn

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE

ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

COPY decision_trees /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program

However, when building the container from a Jupyter Labs file, it gives an error saying "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlforecast==0.13.1" and listing available versions only up to 0.9.3. Which came out almost a year ago.

I tried to run the file with different versions of Ubuntu and with different modifier such as "--no-use-wheel --allow-all-external --allow-unverified blinker" but these all generated different errors prior to reaching the version error.

You have a fairly old Ubuntu base version, does using ubuntu:24.04 make any difference?  Do you have this setup running in a non-Docker virtual environment, so you could run pip freeze to get a requirements.txt file?

Mentioning the Python version would be useful. mlforecast 0.9.3 seems to work with 3.6, anything above that does not.

You're using Ubuntu 18.04, which was released in 2018. It's likely that the version of Python installed there is too old for newer version of that package. If I use ubuntu:24.04, which includes Python 3.12, I can pip install mlforecast==0.13.1 without errors.

@larsks, I had thought of that and previously tried to run it with 24.04. However when running with that version of Ubuntu, an error occurs on the "RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip". Which states: "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/pip': File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
Error response from daemon: No such image: sagemaker-decision-trees:latest"

So, don't create that symlink. The python3-pip package already provides /usr/bin/pip.

If I remove that line it now gives me the error: "error: externally-managed-environment" on the first install line

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment

Ubuntu 18.04 runs with Python 3.6 and the latest versions of mlforecast require Python >= 3.8
