Module is suddenly not found, and can't install it either with pip
Yesterday I was working on my project. Today, when I opened it, two modules aren't found. Yesterday they were, so that is pretty strange already. When I try to install using pip, it says 'Requirement already satisfied'. The modules I need to install are these:
from decouple import config
from celery.schedules import crontab

I already surfed around the internet trying random things, since I am new and learning django and python I find my problem very hard to understand.
EDIT:
this might be helpful, but when I use pip, I get this error:
just@4G05D8DPAA4A78D hockeyvoorspeller % pip3 install decouple
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
use a virtual environment:

python3 -m venv path/to/venv
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install xyz

If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with

brew install pipx

You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
will permanently disable this error.

If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.

Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your 
Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override 
this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by 
passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade pip

This might help solving the issue, thanks in advance

This question is similar to: What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Alternate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3

Can you share the screen shot of errror message, including IDE( like VS code, Intellij etc).

If you have created a virtual environment, activate it and try again,
env\scripts\activate use this code

Yesterday I installed the packages without a venv. Today when I opened it the packages were gone so I made a venv. Installing in the venv goes fine, but in the python file it still doesnt find the packages

Do you get errors when the virtual environment is active?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
