Cannot Import a python Module from a package that is installed in Ubuntu
Before I talk about the problem, I cannot use pip directly in ubuntu, I have to set a python virtual environment first. whenever I do that outside the environment I get this message :
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

I installed a package called mamba-ssm using pip. and I am using command line to run a python script that imports a module from mamba ssm like this :
`from mamba_ssm.ops.triton.ssd_combined import mamba_chunk_scan_combined`

but when I run the script I get this error message :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named mamba_ssm.ops.triton.ssd_combined
But when I run python in the terminal and import the module it gets imported.
I tried :
export PYTHONPATH=home/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mamba_ssm:$PYTHONPATH
then running my code.
I tried executing the code using python of the venv I created :
/home/venv/bin/python
added from mamba_ssm.ops.triton.ssd_combined import mamba_chunk_scan_combined to __init__py
nothing works.

Are you activating your virtual environment correctly? You shouldn't need to change your PYTHONPATH, running <project folder>\Scripts\activate.sh should be all you need.

It appears that you pasted a github link into another comment - can you [edit] that into your question for reference?

Btw, the first part of your question probably isn't necessary. It's also answered by this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75608323

Maybe the pip or pip3 that you used was not provided by the virtual env; e.g. you didn't activate the venv, or you used a different shell, ... or something like that.  And you actually installed the module outside of the venv.  If you are uncertain, you can run which pip or which pip3 to figure out where the command comes from.  (It should be in the venv's bin directory if you are trying to install in a venv.)

@importrandom yes I activated the venv correctly.

@Andrew I just wanted to note that I am working in an extrenally managed environement in case this has something to do with my main problem.

@Stephen I am using venv's pip

@FadiaBkf Externally managed environments are the default on most *nix systems I've seen. Venvs are almost always required when working with Python packages.

Something is probably going on with your venv or your installation of mamba. I was able to get your sample working by running these commands in the terminal:
sudo apt install python3-venv
python3 -m venv mambaenv
source mambaenv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install torch
python3 -m pip install mamba-ssm

You can verify whether or not that worked using this Python script:
from mamba_ssm.ops.triton.ssd_combined import mamba_chunk_scan_combined
print(mamba_chunk_scan_combined) # <function mamba_chunk_scan_combined at [address]>


I ran thses commands in my terminal and got this  '''
ImportError: cannot import name 'sym_float' from partially initialized module 'torch' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/fadia/mambaenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/init.py) '''

@FadiaBkf Does a script with nothing but "import torch" throw the same error? If so, that might be worth its own question.

@Andrew no it doesn't,

I solved it by placing the script itself in the venv folder, I tried copying the whole folder of the project in there but the problems persists. the .py file itself should be in /home/'name'/venv directory

Have you tried cloning your module from the Git Repo directly in your virtual environment, instead of using pip command ?
Also, restarting the venv, ide, kernel, is the kind of step we forget too often.
Fortunately, in Colab Notebook, they raise an issue and you are asked to restart your kernel for changes to take effect.
Also, your error message hinted me at this documentation, which I think you should read for your general understanding of this particular error message.
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/externally-managed-environment-pep-668/
In order to complete the first idea, here is what I encountered multiple times and it relate to something as simple as using Whisper locally to transcribe audio files.
In the whisper documentation, there are multiple ways of doing this and there lies the situation you are describing:
if I installed Whisper using pip, I encountered issues similar to the one you are describing.
Whisper Local Install
After using the git repo, no more issues.
Sometime you need to consider cache, and other building issues like the "wheels". But it always resolve in the end, by doing it this way.
Hope it helps in the resolution of your issue

hey there thank you for your reply. The mamba I'm working with isn't the package manager it's actually a deep learning layer called mamba-ssm https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba

cool, same, same. I sometime get difficulties in Colab Notebook, and it's the same idea. You should try cloning the repo, and also restarting your (kernel, idea or venv)

Check the link I gave you, it actually show you everything, with explanations. They suggest an easy way out with pipx, but I would definitely consider cloning and restarting in your venv.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
