# What should I do with --user installed packages on Debian? (in light of PEP668)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian

In light of some [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) ([Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) at least) steering away from

`python3 -m pip install numpy`

what should I do with my user packages that I had installed with `python3 -m pip install --user numpy` (for instance)?

They are located in `python3 -m site --user-site` : `~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`.

I don't want to:

1. delete `/usr/lib/python3.x/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED`
2. install `pipx`
3. sometimes, of course, cannot find an `apt` managed package

I'm all for using `venv`, but do I make some `~/.local/lib/python3/packages` folder and include it in a PYTHON_PATH, but also make that folder a `venv` virtual environment? Should I move what is in my `~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` folder to this new folder, or re-download?

For someone who uses Python and 'standard' packages, I really don't need to worry about mixing things too much, but to me it seems (only for me as a low-key user) that functionally there is little difference between `venv` installs in one directory (one for each project) and `--user` installs in another.

I've looked around a lot about this but couldn't find a "here's what to do" tutorial on adopting the change. Or maybe I am missing some big picture...

[How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" everytime I use pip3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-everytime-i-use-pip3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-manag)

[pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-manag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use `pipenv` to manage my packages, but to install it, I have to do a pip install. I wanted to do this just for my user, so I created a local venv for it,

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/
apt install python3-pip
python3 -m venv ~/.local/share/pipenv
source ~/.local/share/pipenv/bin/activate
```

and installed `pipenv` on it:

```
pip install pipenv
```

To now use pipenv with my user, I added the path to the pipenv bin venv to my PATH:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/share/pipenv/bin:$PATH
```

Now I can use pipenv to manage the project venvs. It's kinda convoluted, I know, but Python can be quite convoluted with packages.

Comment: What did you do with your (if you had any) local or global packages? I've tried your solution and it works great. I found myself using "pipenv" for multiple projects, as mine are relatively simple... thus making it the same as the "user" package library...

Comment: I keep them outside the project. Global projects are handled by apt, and local packages are in my user area.