# Best practice using python packages, not developing on Debian 12

Tags: python, debian, python-module

What is the best way to install some Python packages on Debian 12, not for developing something, but for just using some modules?

I would like to use sphinx and a related style package [furo](https://pypi.org/project/furo/) in combination with a git hook post-update.

Previously, I just installed them via pip and everything goes fine.
On Debian 12, I (re)installed sphinx via pipx as a normal user successfully, however, I could not install furo because it does not provide executable with it (I guess).

Then, at least, I have two choice to install furo via

`pip install --user furo --break-system-packages`

as a normal user or via

`pip install --break-system-packages`

as root.

It would not be the best way. I guess we can use venv (to call it in the post-update script for the git directory), but it is too much for my usage. Is there any easy and better way?

Comment: `pip` is not Debian package manager. `apt` is, so unless you are willing to create `*.deb` packages with the software, I'd say it's irrelevant you use Debian

Comment: I understand pip is not Debian package manager. My question is what is the best way to install python module not provided as *.deb packages. The previously most straightforward way is simply to install it via pip, but now it is not recommended because of PEP668.

Comment: virtual env and add missing packages into it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, virtual env is the most straightforward way now. For python modules with some executable such as sphinx-build, pipx is the easiest way, which uses virtual env internally. It works completely fine without explicitly using venv. I'm just curious about a way to install some python modules without executable such as furo, a Sphinx style provided as a python package.

Comment: I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971804/what-should-i-do-with-user-installed-packages-on-debian-in-light-of-pep668 and its reference and guess use of --break-system-packages is not so bad idea for my case, isn't it?