# How to install pipenv on Ubuntu 23 after PEP 668?

Tags: ubuntu, pipenv

I used pipenv on Ubuntu 22. Then I upgraded the OS to version 23, so pipenv stopped working, and it is impossible to install it now with a system pip.

```
# pip3 install pipenv
error: externally-managed-environment
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

PEP 668 apparently prevents using system python for personal use cases and wants me to use virtualenvs. But this is exactly why I want to install pipenv in the first place. So it is kind of a chicken and egg problem. What is the best way to install pipenv from now on?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-manag/75696359#75696359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could install pipenv via `apt install pipenv`.