# How to install Jupyter Lab on Debian 12 bookworm?

Tags: python, debian, jupyter-lab

- In Debian 11 I had installed jupyter lab with pip in my user directory, but on Debian 12 this is not possible anymore since [Debian decided to follow pep-668](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#python3-pep-668) and python packages are marked as externally managed, you can only install system wide with the package manager (APT).
- I installed python3-jupyterlab-server lab with APT, but it fails to start

  ```
   $ sudo apt reinstall python3-jupyterlab-server
  ...
  ...
  Preparing to unpack .../python3-jupyterlab-server_2.16.5-1_all.deb ...
  Unpacking python3-jupyterlab-server (2.16.5-1) over (2.16.5-1) ...
  Setting up python3-jupyterlab-server (2.16.5-1) ...

  $ jupyter lab
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
      from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'
  ```
- I installed Jupyter Lab with pip in a virtual environment and can successfully start it from there. Is this the only way?

I understand the value of virtual environments or conda for maintaining a lot of data analysis packages. But Jupyter Lab is now a core component of the system, so I guess it should be installed system-wide with the system package manage (APT on Debian). I'm wondering what's wrong in my config, why can't I start jupyter lab when installed from apt?

Related questions:

- [How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75608323/2641825)
- [pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75602063/2641825)

Comment: Could [JupyterLab Desktop](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop) be a solution? It has deb packages available (but no ppa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing `pipx` via `apt` and then installing it via `pipx install jupyterlab`?

It is an alternative way of installing packages mentioned in the first link.

Comment: I did try `pipx install jupyterlab` but `jupyter lab` failed to start yesterday. I had just done the Debian upgrade from bullseye 11 to bookworm 12. After a restart this morning `jupyter lab` does work now, thank you.

Comment: The problem with pipx is that it can only install system-wide python applications that are meant to be started at the command line, such as `jupyter lab`. I still need to manage a separate jupyter kernel to install the required packages. So in the end I start a virtual environment `source /path_to_env/bin/activate`, install jupyter lab with pip in that environment and start `jupyter lab` from there, as I wrote in the original question.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it working. Still curious why the "intended" way didn't work...