# Is installing conan via pip still recommended?

Tags: pip, conan

The installation guide of [conan 1](https://docs.conan.io/1/installation.html) and [conan 2](https://docs.conan.io/2/installation.html) claims that the recommended way of installation is using:

```bash
pip install conan
```

As explained or at least alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana), python is preferring virtual environments nowadays, which is why a pip installation on my distro (Debian on WSL) is throwing the `This environment is externally managed` error. Fair.

The recommended solution is to install via:

```bash
sudo apt install python3-[package name]
```

Well, I don't think there is a `python3-conan` package, at least none that default-configured apt would find.

The simple solution to installing conan is downloading the [installer](https://conan.io/downloads). Is this the recommended installation method now? Is there an apt-installable package under a different name? Or have I fundamentally misunderstood something about python's virtual environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Conan installation via pip is the recommended because its easiest way by using a single command. Of course, there are some limitations like minimal python version installe, or pipx in case using newer distros.

Still, you can use other installers, like the Debian one. Those installers are **recommended too**, is just a preference. You should **try** them and use what better fits your case. They are updated following the latest Conan version available.

For those installers that are listed to be used via native package manager (e.g. `yay -S conan`), the conan package distributed there is not officially maintained by Conan team, but by the open source community. Keep it in mind in case you have some error when installing and finding some error.