# UWSGI Binary is not in '/usr/local/bin'

Tags: pip, uwsgi, sudo, mv, pipx

For starting the uwsgi service, I need the uwsgi binary to be in the file /usr/local/bin off of the root. When I try sudo pip install uwsgi, I get an error message that looks like this:
[pip install error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHYVX.png)

What I've tried:

- aptitude install uwsgi (doesnt recognize aptitude)
- using pipx to install uwsgi (downloads uwsgi to /home/pqadmin/.local/bin, tried moving using mv uwsgi /usr/local/bin and it told me permission denied. I tried doing that both with sudo using pqadmin and in the root and both said permission denied).

What can I do to get uwsgi in the right directory?

Thank you so much for the help. I'm totally new to website management.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread, which explains pip's externally managed environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana