# global python library installation where pipx is not an option

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, pipx

I understand as of [PEP-0668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) we're supposed to be installing python executables via `pipx`. What about packages such as a [mopidy](https://mopidy.com/) plugin [mopidy-spotify](https://mopidy.com/ext/spotify/)? It doesn't install via `pipx`, and as mopidy service is ran as `mopidy` user it should be installed globally.

Is `sudo python3 -m pip install Mopidy-Spotify --break-system-packages` appropriate in such situation?

Edit: let's assume mopidy itself was installed via OS package manager, eg from [apt](https://packages.debian.org/testing/mopidy).

---

See also: [pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana)

Comment: Use [`pipx inject`](https://pipx.pypa.io/stable/examples/#pipx-inject-example) to add the package to an existing mopidy install.

Comment: @ivvija nice idea, but that implies mopidy itself was installed from pypi as opposed to system pkg repository.

Comment: What about using the apt repository for this plugin? See also https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/debian/

Comment: @sinoroc that's where I'm installing mopidy itself from. But not all plugins are available there, plus the fixes take usually months to be built into the deb releases, which is why installing from github tends to be the preferred method.

Comment: @laur Then the other way around, have you considered [installing everything (including Mopidy itself) from PyPI](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/pypi/)? Meaning you would create a virtual environment where you are free to install whatever plugins you want, without worrying about breaking the system Python environment. It has its drawbacks of course (no automatic security updates). -- And then, otherwise, I guess it is fine to bypass the PEP 668 with `--break-system-packages` as long as you know what you are doing (you know the dependencies will not clash). -- Me I would use apt.

Comment: I guess you could have two installations. One from apt, which is stable and secure. One from PyPI, that you have to manage yourself, but where you are free to experiment with the latest versions of the plugins (including unreleased versions, directly from GitHub).