# How to install pipenv in "externally managed environment"

Tags: pip, debian, raspberry-pi4, pipenv

I want to use pipenv for managing my virtual Python environments.  In a freshly built Debian (on RPi4B):

```
    % pip install pipenv
```

fails with

```
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
```

and it goes on to suggest that I use a virtual environment.  But that's why I'm installing pipenv in the first place!

I could not find updated info on how to install pipenv -- how does one resolve this chicken and egg problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-manag/75696359#75696359)

Short answer: Use venv to create a venv, then inside that venv, install pipenv.