# import paho.mqtt.client as PahoMQTT, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'

Tags: debian, mqtt, python-venv, raspberry-pi4, paho

I'm encountering an issue while trying to import the Paho MQTT module in my Python script on my Raspberry Pi. Despite using `pip install paho-mqtt`, the module doesn't seem to be successfully installed, as I'm still facing an import error.

[image: error-->]

I've already tried reinstalling the module and ensuring that Python is up to date on my Raspberry Pi. I've also verified the installation of the Paho MQTT module using `pip show paho-mqtt`, which confirms that it's not installed.

I suspect there might be an issue with the Python environment or the path configuration.

[image: environment--->]

I'm running Python 3 on my Raspberry Pi.

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I expected the Paho MQTT module to be successfully installed after executing `pip install paho-mqtt`.

I expected `pip show paho-mqtt` to confirm the successful installation of the module.

I expected my Python environment to be correctly configured to import and use the Paho MQTT module without any errors.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text (especially photos of screens). They are very hard to read, impossible for users of screen readers and totally unsearchable. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it as code.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the error message?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-paho-mqtt`

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696359/11810946).