How to install SMB library on Raspberry Pi 5 using Python 3.11
When I go to run a script I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Double_Welds/Dbl_Welds.py", line 29, in <module>
    from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smb'

How do I install 'smb' module if I am using python 3.11 on a raspberry pi 5?

You seem to have installed it before? Did you use pip? What happens when you try to install it following the docs? https://pypi.org/project/pysmb/

I have installed it before on a windows pc using pip. When I follow the docs and run 'pip install pysmb' my terminal it gives me an error saying 'externally-managed-environment'

The full error asks you to create a virtualenv, which is best practice for any Python project. There are some solutions to that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602063/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-is-failing-this-environment-is-externally-mana

pip3 install pysmb --break-system-package
