# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' in docker run time error

Tags: docker, flask, devops

```
root@ip-172-31-40-102:~# docker logs 47821a8d780a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.9 AS backend-builder

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the backend code into the container
COPY ./backend /app

# Install Python dependencies, including Flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#------------------Stage 1 Ends----------------------
#------------------Stage 2 Start---------------------
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the code from the backend-builder stage
COPY --from=backend-builder /app /app

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 5000

# Command to run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

i want run the docker container but i not able to run contarinter i facing this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

please help to understand how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

You are only installing your requirements to the build stage, they are not available globally in the final stage.

What you have in the final stage is only what you copy with this

```
COPY --from=backend-builder /app /app
```

and since you are not using a virtual env but installing requirements globally, you are not copying whatever you install with

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Solution 1

A solution that would work for this particular Dockerfile would be to *not* do a multistage build, since you are not installing anything heavy in the build stage, basically only stuff that you need for the final stage anyway.

So something like this should work:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the backend code into the container
COPY ./backend /app

# Install Python dependencies, including Flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 5000

# Command to run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

### Solution 2

If you have more stuff going on in the build stage that you don't want in the final image, your solution needs a virtual env step so that requirements are installed locally.

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48562835/6845813.