# Do we need to create virtual environment if we are using docker, in django project?

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker

Do we need virtual environment if we are using docker, in django project?

Comment: No need, the docker container is something isolated, and I'm sure that you won't put more than one project in the same container.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146792/why-people-create-virtualenv-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Most Python Dockerfiles don't install a virtual environment; activating it is mechanically a little tricky, and the Docker image itself provides sufficient isolation from other Pythons.  But a host virtual environment is still extremely useful for day-to-day development.